# jQuery, don't reload - somehow

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have a small problem with my jQuery script.

```
<script language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.roll-li').click(function(){
                    if ($('.hideshow').is(":hidden")) {
                        $('.hideshow').slideDown("slow");
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.hideshow').slideUp("slow");
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
```

How to modify script, so div that div with class "hideshow" that I'm slideing up and down, will be hidden on default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In css,

```
.hideshow { display: none; }
```

In jquery (no need for checking visibility, just use slideToggle()

```
$(".roll-li").click(function() {
    $(".hideshow").slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
});
```

(also consider changing your html to use ids instead of classes, as finding these via jquery is more efficient)

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need to do that in the script.  You just put `style="display: none"` on the div, or add `display: none` to the CSS for `.hideshow`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.hideshow').hide();
            $('.roll-li').click(function(){
                if ($('.hideshow').is(":hidden")) {
                    $('.hideshow').slideDown("slow");
                }
                else {
                    $('.hideshow').slideUp("slow");
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Just add the line:

```
$('.hideshow').hide();
```

That's if I understood your question properly.